# In kotlin can i Init an object and set a paramater in one line

Tags: kotlin

class:

```
class CameraBrandDto(override val id: Long = 0, override var dateCreated: Date = Date(), override var dateUpdated: Date = Date()) : DataTransportObject {
    override var clazz = this.javaClass.simpleName.replace("Dto", "")

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 13)
    var name: String = ""

    var models: MutableSet<DtoMin> = mutableSetOf(DtoMin(0, "UNDEFINED", "UNDEFINED", Date(), Date()))

}
```

I would like to accomplish this in one line

```
val axisDto  = CameraBrandDto()
axisDto.name = "AXIS"
```

is this possible???

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just use the standard library function [`.apply { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html), which executes [the lambda with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) on the object and returns that object:

```
val axisDto = CameraBrandDto().apply { name = "AXIS" }
```